# Adding a NameSpace to an XmlDocument by CreateAttribute("xmlns") doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I create an `XmlDocument` in code, I add a namespace to it with `XmlNamespaceManager` and then try to query the document. It fails to find the element, however if I `doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml)` it goes on to find the element.

So `doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml)` is a hack that doesn't make sense to me:

a) why doesn't my code work without it?
b) why does it work with it?

```
        var ns = "http://made.up/uri";
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

        var policies = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("policies"));
        var att = policies.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns"));

        att.Value = ns;
        var policy = policies.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("policy"));
        policy.InnerText="bla";

        // doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml); // if I uncomment this the SelectNodes() below works

        var namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        namespaces.AddNamespace("pol", ns);

        var policyNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//pol:policy", namespaces);

        if (policyNodes.Count == 0){
            Console.WriteLine("No policy nodes");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Found policy nodes");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml + "\n" + DateTime.Now);
```

Dotnet fiddle here :
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DQGwH2

Comment: Consider using XDocument instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer.

If you want to add a namespace to an XmlDocument, you do it by adding it as an argument to your `CreateElement()`

If you just create an attribute with `xmlns="namespace"` it doesn't scope anything as in that namespace (it's just an attribute.)

as in:
 `var policies = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("policies","http://namespace.uri"));`

That's why `doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml)` works, it *actually* reads it as a namespace

updated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/sNdH6R